# Error importing BSON document, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, bson

I am trying to import a sample BSON file `test.bson` into MongoDB. The server is already running, so I use

```
mongoimport --db test --collection foo --drop --file test.bson
```

However, I get the following error:

```
2016-01-24T13:51:06.126-0500    connected to: localhost
2016-01-24T13:51:06.144-0500    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'è' looking for beginning of value
2016-01-24T13:51:06.144-0500    imported 0 documents
```

(1) How does one get around this error, `invalid character 'è' looking for beginning of value`? What exactly should I do to access the data in `test.bson`?

(2) Is there any other way to import data using MongoDB? If I am in the shell and type

```
$mongo
```

how can I import json/bson files?

(BSON is a binary representation of JSON with additional type information.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need mongorestore instead of mongoimport. So try

```
mongorestore --db test --collection foo --drop test.bson
```

From the docs:

> WARNING:
>
> Avoid using mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance production backups. They do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types, because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON. Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in MongoDB Backup Methods for this kind of functionality.

mongoimport and mongoexport are used with json-like representations of the data (although it also works with CSV and TSV). mongorestore and mongoexport are for bson.

Comment: This should be correct. The file `--file` is not used either. 

When I try this, I afterwards cannot find the data though. `$mongo` then `db.test.foo.find().pretty()` outputs nothing. Why is this?

Comment: When you use the mongorestore command, do you get the same error message as above? If so, your test.bson file may be corrupt in some way (for example, this could happen if you're not using mongoexport to create it). Another thing to try is converting the test data to JSON and mongoimport. If mongoimport with some test JSON data **doesn't** work, you're database may be corrupt.

Comment: Actually, I figured out my error. The command should be `db.foo.find().pretty()`, as `db` refers to `test`. Thanks!

Comment: you saved my day